# How to multiply two two nth elements of a list in F#

Tags: f#

So i am trying to multiply the nth element of one list with the nth element of another list and add them together

```
 let listMulti xList yList =
 |> [for x in xList do
       for y in yList do
           yield x*y ] // multiplies all the elements on x with y
 |> List.filter(fun x-> List.nth % List.length (xList) =1 ) //gets the elements 1 , 4, 7 for a list of size 3. This is scalable
 |> List.sum //add them all up
```

So the idea here is

```
>listMulti [1;2;3][4;5;6];;
val it : int = 32
```

So 1*4 + 2 *5 + 3*6 = 32
,but instead im getting

error FS0010: Unexpected infix operator in binding

Help?

Answer (score 3):

The error is because you are using `List.nth` in a weird way.

I would do something like

```
List.zip xlist ylist
|> List.sumBy (fun (a,b) -> a*b)
```

Here `list.zip` combines the lists - so if you had `[1;2;3]` and `[4;5;6]` you get `[(1,4);(2,5);(3,6)]`.  Then you just multiply and sum in one go.

Comment: I cant get this to work.  I'm new to F# and cant find any information on List.zip2 online. I found List.zip and tried to make my curried function work around it, but I don't seem to understand it. Can you be more explicit on the implementation of this?

Comment: That was a mistake, I was writing without the compiler - should have just been zip.  Added some explaination

Comment: Thanks one last question. I'm getting
"Expecting a type supporting the operator '+' but given a function type. You may be missing an argument to a function.:"

 let inner xList yList =
     List.zip xList yList
         |> List.sum (fun (a,b) -> a*b)

Why is that? Isn't List.zip xList yList returning the list into the pipeline?

Comment: nvm i got it. Thanks again